# Why do some UIViewController properties become nil when not set using viewDidLoad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uikit

This seems to happen when I am using a nib file to load the view . I need to set the datasources and delegates for some custom views progammatically . They work only if i set them in the viewDidLoad method . Setting them in the initializer , awakeFromNib etc all fail. Does anyone know the reason for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a view controller from a nib file, the UIViewController is first initialized and then loaded. So when the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is called `self.view` and any other views loaded from the nib will be `nil`. Also it may happen that the views are unloaded (see `viewDidUnload`). That's why any view-related initialization needs to happen in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Are there any exceptions to this rule ?

Comment: I 've read the documentation but a clear and concise explanation of nib file loading would work : Is it : send all objects alloc message ,send all objects initWithCoder or Init .. eventually call viewDidLoad

Comment: There are reams and reams of documentation on this. Sometimes, it feels like there's too much. Read the NIB Files section of the Resource Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8